# random banner with individual link on shopify

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

Below I have code that shows one of the preset banner randomly.

However I want to have individual link for each of the banner.

As you can see in the code, currently it only has one same link for every banner.
Can anyone advice ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var imageCount = 4;
  $(function(){ 
    var whichImage=get_random();
    var image=new Array(imageCount)
    image[0] = "<img src=\"{{ 'HADER-AO-UNTUK-DI-BI-5.jpg' | asset_url }}\" />";
    image[1] = "<img src=\"{{ 'HADER-AO-UNTUK-DI-BI-6.jpg' | asset_url }}\" />";
    image[2] = "<img src=\"{{ 'HADER-AO-UNTUK-DI-BI-7.jpg' | asset_url }}\" />";
    image[3] = "<img src=\"{{ 'HADER-AO-UNTUK-DI-BI-8.jpg' | asset_url }}\" />";  
    function get_random() { 
      var ranNum= Math.floor(Math.random()* imageCount );
      return ranNum;
    }
    $('#randimage p a').prepend(image[whichImage]);
  });
</script>

<div id="randimage" align="center"><p><a href="https://alatolahraga.id"></a></p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways, this is not the best, but fit in your code.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        const image= [
            "<a href=\"https://alatolahraga.id\"><img src=\"{{ 'HADER-AO-UNTUK-DI-BI-5.jpg' | asset_url }}\" /></a>",
            "<a href=\"https://alatolahraga.id\"><img src=\"{{ 'HADER-AO-UNTUK-DI-BI-6.jpg' | asset_url }}\" /></a>",
            "<a href=\"https://alatolahraga.id\"><img src=\"{{ 'HADER-AO-UNTUK-DI-BI-7.jpg' | asset_url }}\" /></a>",
            "<a href=\"https://alatolahraga.id\"><img src=\"{{ 'HADER-AO-UNTUK-DI-BI-8.jpg' | asset_url }}\" /></a>"
        ];
        const whichImage=get_random();
        function get_random() {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * image.length );
        }
        $('#randimage p').prepend(image[whichImage]);
    });
</script>

<div id="randimage" align="center"><p></p></div>
```